# Intercepting Outgoing calls from Web API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented a WEB API and from this I am calling to other WEB API and WCF services. I want to implement logging mechanism in my WEB API with request and response details. I am able to trace the incoming calls to this web API using action filters. 
Is it possible to intercept the outgoing calls which capture the request and response for this scenario.

Comment: how are you making those external calls? Can you post your code? If you `override` the `OnActionExecuted` method in your filter, you'll be able to access and do whatever with the `Response` property of `HttpActionExecutedContext ` instance.

Comment: Do you want to capture the request/responses from wcf or just the request/responses from your api?